# Find the function f(x) when the equation of the derivative of f(x) is given.

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

This is what is given: $f '(x)=y=4x-5$

Find: the function, $f(x)$, of which $f '(x)$ is the derivative of.

Comment: There is no "the function $f$". There are infinitely many functions such that $f'(x)=4x-5$.

Comment: I have an idea of what the function might be: f(x)=2x^2-5x, but I need to show how I got it using the definition of the derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

$$\int \:\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)dx=F\left(x\right)+constnat$$

In your case:

$\int \:\left(4x-5\right)dx=F\left(x\right)+constant$

Can you find $F(x)$?

Comment: Oh, I understand. since taking the derivative of a constant makes the derivative =0, then there is no clear way to get the exact function.

Comment: I used the rules of derivatives to get the equation f(x)=2x^2-5x but how can I show that using the definition of the derivative and a point?

Comment: Your function is F(x)+Constant. $F(x)=(4/2)x^2-5x$. So your function is $2x^2-5x+Constant$. Based on the given information the constant could assume any value not function of $x$ and can't be determined exactly. In case of definite integration, there is no constant but this is not your case.

Comment: Is there any way to get an accurate answer for f'(2) then?

Comment: The best we can do is $f(2)=2*2*2-5*2+C=C-2$, where $C$ is a constant value. You could very well assume a value of it, depending on your specific problem/case.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

your $f(x)= 2x^2-5x +C$ is unique up to a constant $C$.